# Flexbox, image bigger than div shrinks in safari but not in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, flexbox

https://jsfiddle.net/MR_Coder/uo91um49/

In Safari once the browser starts to squish the image, the image starts to shrink.

What I want is the behavior in Chrome, the browser shrinks but the image stays at the same size.

Could someone test this in chrome and in safari to see what I mean?

HTML:

```
<div class="expand">
<img src="#" alt="driving me nuts">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.expand
 {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     background-color: red;
 }
```

I apologize for that weird code. First time posting, won't let me post without code if I have a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like Bootstrap does for responsive images. Use the .image-responsive class on the image. It will scale both the smaller image and the larger image.

```css
.expand
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}
.image-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
  <p>smaller works</p>
<div class="expand">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="driving me nuts" class="image-responsive">
</div>

  <p>  bigger doesn't  </p>
<div class="expand">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x150" alt="driving me nuts"  class="image-responsive">
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like a good work around, but not quite what I had originally set out to make. So now is it against the guidelines to mark a question as the right answer if it technically doesn't answer the question asked?

Answer (score 0):

just add width of image in percents

```
img.w70p {
  width: 70%;
}

<img class="w70p" ...
```

And it will always be 70% width

Comment: Tried adding this. Still seems to work as intended in Chrome, in safari the image still shrinks horizontally.

Comment: works perfect for me. just tested on safari & chrome & firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/uo91um49/2/